# Aptana plugin crashes Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, plugins, crash, aptana, eclipse-indigo

I use Eclipse EE Indigo on a Ubuntu 11.04 laptop. I use the Sun JDK. When I installed the aptana plugin using help/install new software and then installed aptana by pasting

http://download.aptana.com/studio3/plugin/install

into the "work with" field, it installed just fine and then prompted me to restart Eclipse. Now, I cannot start Eclipse anymore at all. It opens but crashes, seemingly when trying to initiate the aptana plugin.

This is a major problem for me because my Eclipse was already very customized and I need to be able to work. I haven't been able to find any info on how to solve this issue on the web. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I noticed that right before Eclipse crashes, this message from the Aptana plugin is printed in the console: aptana javascript scripting console started

Comment: Sorry you had to go through that. Was this version 3.0.4? I'm wondering if it has something to do with the browser trying to launch...there was nothing else in the crash log?

Comment: If anyone else runs into this situation, adding a Java VM argument of -Dstudio.portalBrowser=swt and seeing if that helps would be helpful.

Comment: I never checked the crash log.

The version was whatever version was being made available through http://download.aptana.com/studio3/plugin/install yesterday.

Seemingly I'm not alone in having problems with the plugin.

https://aptanastudio.tenderapp.com/discussions/problems/1001-eclipse-351-crashes-on-startup-after-installation-of-aptana-studio-20

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=304149

https://aptanastudio.tenderapp.com/discussions/problems/2424-aptana-plugin-crashes-eclipse

Comment: Those are for Aptana Studio 2.0, which used XulRunner on Linux--which can be notoriously problematic, which is the reason it was switched to embed Chromium. Well, if anyone does run across the issue again, knowing if that flag helps would be useful. Thanks!

Comment: No worries mate, thanks for your concern. Sorry I cant be more useful, Im not that experienced in Eclipse and its inner workings.

Comment: Thank you for the hint!
I had the same problem on eclipse Indigo and your tip solved the problem.

Comment: I have the same issue on eclipse indigo in Ubuntu. Tried adding       -Dstudio.portalBrowser=swt to eclipse.ini but the issue still remains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an emergency fix that allowed me to start using Eclipse again. It is very blunt and NOT the way you'd expect to deal with problems like this, alas, it seems at least my Eclipse is up and running again.

Because Eclipse crashed very shortly after having started up, it was impossible to uninstall the plugin that crashed it. What I did was the following:

- Make sure Eclipse is not running.
- Make a backup copy of the Eclipse folder.
- Navigate to the folder in the terminal
- Execute this command in terminal:

  ```
  find . -name *aptana* -exec rm -rf {} \;
  ```

Note that this works for me because I am the owner and have the necessary permissions to perform this operation in my Eclipse folder. If you are not the owner of the Eclipse folder, or if you lack some permissions, chances are you may have to insert sudo before the rest of the command in order for it to work.

This command will search the current folder and all subfolders for any files and folders that has the string aptana in their names, and delete all of them.

- Execute

  ```
  find . -name *aptana*
  ```

in terminal to confirm that there is nothing left. There should be no results when running this command. If you get some results, then all aptana files and folders have still not been deleted.

- Should the previous command leave no results, start Eclipse.
- Go to Help/Install new software and then click What is already installed?
- Select the Aptana plugin and press uninstall.
- Restart Eclipse when prompted to do so.

Eclipse should now work just like before you installed Aptana. At least my Eclipse seems to do so.

Comment: Rather than posting a stub answer and putting a solution in the question itself it's better to post a full complete answer as a completely separate thing to the question.