# Cannot start eclipse after having Aptana installed

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, aptana

I recently installed the Aptana plugin into my eclipse IDE and restarted it. Now it doesnt start at all.

I tried deleting the metadata folder and it made it start but crash soon after.

However before crashing there was a message that my version of Aptana is incompatible with firefox (its funny what does firefox has to do with it?).

Anyway after the crash I had three .txt files in my eclipse folder saying that

> A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment

Please help me start eclipse.

**Possible duplicate:**
[Aptana plugin crashes Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7103069/aptana-plugin-crashes-eclipse)

But this question isnt properly answered.

Comment: I would go with installing aptana standalone (which is eclipse anyway) and then putting back in the additional plugins that you like to use.

Comment: Could you please tell me how to uninstall my current aptana plugin in order to make eclipse work?

Comment: Note: This is only how I would attempt it. I haven't tried this. -- First, close eclipse and backup your eclipse folder. Next, go through the features and plugins folders and remove all files and folders that reference "aptana".

Comment: Okay so I deleted server.jetty and server.cloud folders and it started working. Thank you very much!

Comment: Another question: I have JavaScript installed but it still says you dont have any javascript libraries and when I click install javascript libraries it does nothing.

Comment: I'll re-post it as an answer for you.

Comment: I'm not sure, I haven't used any javascript helpers in eclipse yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest starting with aptana to begin with if you want to use aptana. However, if that isn't an option and you simply want to remove it from eclipse, you can try this:

**Note: This is only how I would attempt it. I haven't tried this.**

First, close eclipse and backup your eclipse folder. Next, go through the features and plugins folders and remove all files and folders that reference "aptana".

Comment: Sorry another question: Having aptana plugin installed, how should I proceed learning jQuery? Or should I discard this approach and adapt a better one?

Comment: That depends on what method helps you learn the best. I learned jQuery by diving right in and using it without any documentation, just "seeing what works". When I hit walls, I went to the documentation for answers. Others learn best by reading books and tutorials. I personally don't see any good coming out of using code-completion for jQuery since the jQuery API changes so frequently.

Comment: Okay I'm using a text-editor for now. Just to be sure, by code-completion do you mean content assist?

Comment: Yes. That is just an opinion though. I tried using a content assist eclipse plugin for jQuery a while back and found that they never kept up with the latest version of jQuery.